# How to prevent "automatic" bold version of a font to be wider than regular having the same pt size?

Tags: fonts

I have a monospaced font (`PT Mono`) that I prefer to use in programming IDE's. The font has only `Regular`, all other `Bold` and `Italic` are derived by slanting and "boldification" of the `Regular`. The problem is that the "boldified" characters are wider than regular ones, so the source code strings in the IDE window are now composed of non-monospaced characters.

How do I control the "boldification" of the font so it would not become wider than regular?

The problem is illustrated on the screenshot below (`PT Mono`, no dedicated bold). See how "unsigned char" and "sizeof" words are moving out from their proper positions.

[image: automatic boldification changes the width]

Here an another example, `Droid Sans Mono` (no dedicated bold).
[image]

And here an example when the font has dedicated bold version (`Liberation Mono`). Bold and regular are aligned perfectly.
[image]

So, the issue is definitely in frivolous boldification rendering in situations where bold is not provided. The font engine is to blame.

UPD: There is a file `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/90-synthetic.conf` which if being referenced from `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` tunes the font engine to perform synthetic emboldening of the fonts that do not have the bold version. If the symbolic link to this file is removed from the `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`, the emboldening disappears. This is not what is exactly wanted, but at least this cures the case of monospace fonts being not monospace (see below, `PT Mono`). The fine tuning of the emboldening is still wanted (either by configuration file, or by `freetype2` patch.

[image]

Comment: You can't control that. Font design would be ruined. Even if you precisely reduce size (which you can't) to match regular font spacing, then bold font would look smaller. If you want uniformly spaced font, just don't use bold font... or try terminal

Comment: That's not true. Fonts that have both regular and bold typefaces provided in separate files have same char width in regular and in bold. For example, LetterGothic.

Comment: I stand corrected. I noticed the same using SciTE (and perhaps you too use Scintilla based editor - perhaps Geany?) while my font is Droid Sans Mono, but I took it as granted, and I didn't have an idea that weighted font can have different spacing even for monospaced fonts, while bold font uses same spacing as regular. Even more it seems that also proportional fonts have this "feature" you noticed, thou not all. Sorry for my bold first reply, I should have checked first

Comment: @zetah: I looked thru different font files and looks like that indeed the change of the width only happens when there's no dedicated bold version of the font. I'm going to update the question with more screenshots.

Comment: mentioned also here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ttf-droid/+bug/565393

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**mbaitoff**, I'm posting this as addition to your update, not as an answer

If user creates file named `~/.fonts.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <test name="spacing" compare="eq">
            <const>mono</const>
        </test>
        <edit name="embolden" mode="assign">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

then, applications can use bold monospaced font if available, and disable "synthetic boldification" if used font does not have bold typeface.

It is just alternative, and slightly different approach with different result

Comment: If the symlink `/etc/conf.d/50-user.conf` is renamed to be executed after `90-synthetic.conf`, you don't have to remove embolden completely. `99-user.conf` works fine. Otherwise, `90-synthetic.conf` enables it again.